# How to extract part of location.href in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

In this example, what's the regexp to to extract 'first' from location.href, such as:

http://www.mydomain.com/first/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps not an answer to your question, but if you're writing in Javascript, you probably want to use location.pathname rather than extract it yourself from the entire href.

Comment: +1. Regex should not be one's answer of first resort! location.pathname.split('/')[1] is much easier to understand than the analogous regex.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about split - that works well when I have /first/ and /first/second/

Answer (score 5):

[window.location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Comment: @CMS: because a naked location.pathname does not answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked for a regex solution, this would be it:

```
^(?:[^:]+://)?[^/]+/([^/]+)
```

This matches all of these variants (match group one would contain `"first"` in any case):

- `http://www.mydomain.com/first/`
- `http://www.mydomain.com/first`
- `https://www.mydomain.com/first/`
- `https://www.mydomain.com/first`
- `www.mydomain.com/first/` (this one and the next would be for convenience)
- `www.mydomain.com/first`

To make it "http://"-only, it gets simpler:

```
^http://[^/]+/([^/]+)
```

Comment: really? a regex when it's available as a property?

Comment: @annakata: well, that is what cdillon asked for. But yeah, kinda backwards.

Comment: @annakata: location.pathname would require some post-processing as well, since the OP seems to ask for the "first" part only. Admittedly, this could be done with split("/")[0], but a) I don't see the real drawback of regex here, and b) he may also want to match the rest of the URL for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I changed the regex a bit (made the first group a non-capturing one), so now it should give you this: ["http://www.mydomain.com/first", "first"]. Array position 0 always is the whole match, array position 1 is match group 1.

Comment: I went with the location.pathname, but thanks for the regex answer, I will study it.

Comment: @tomalak: just clarity and a probably insignificant performance hit. The extension of the regex is certainly valuable (and as you point out, the OP probably needs to do *some* string manip on the property, but I think it's likely that it's only simple stuff and the property will be clearer in intent

Comment: I think the "location.pathname" solution is the one that better suits your problem.

Comment: @annakata: Yeah, probably it's also better because avoiding regex for trivial things makes code more maintainable -- especially when you admit to be a "RegExp noob", as the OP did originally. Ah, well. :-)

Comment: For those of you scratching your heads, escaping the backslashes fixed this for me: `match(/^(?:[^:]+:\/\/)?[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)/)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use window.location.host and window.location.search
just check out [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) for details

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /^http:\/\/(www.)?mydomain\.com\/([^\/]*)\//;
var url = "http://mydomain.com/first/";

if(re.test(url)) {
  var matches = url.match(re);
  return matches[2]; // 0 contains whole URL, 1 contains optional "www", 2 contains last group
}
```